# Set up Access table to perform multiple records at time

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I performed some research how do I need to set up my DB but I need your advice how to.

I have few tables in my db ( db is for incoming material ) in this db are below tables:

1. Material table
2. incoming delivery
3. measurements
4. supplier
5. time measurement

Let me explain logic of this db.

When delivery come user will input some data in form (creation of incoming list) where he will basically enter all data necessary to start process of receiving. So once he hit button save record he will create record in tables incoming delivery and time measure.

Until this point everything works perfectly. When next user received this incoming list he got some data where was one hyperlink to file where they put it measurements.

And here come my problem. 
I want data to be input in Access rather than to excel (form input looks much more better [yes this is most important reason  :) ] ). 
So for that I created table called measurements, where I plan input [incoming delivery ID], [material id], [primal key] , and that 41 another columns for measurement(this columns need to be separated cause we have many parts and each got different No. of measurement and user will get information via user form ( opening different form based on material id [this works]).

So after describing its logic I am requesting you people how do i create with 1 record to measurement table each time different numbers of measurements in measurements table for it.

put it even more simple just for case. When user hit button to save the record which creates record in delivery list will also create for example additional 5 records (this number will be based on cell value) in measurement table linked with incoming delivery. (relation is of course set up to one-many)

so in the end when i will create somehow continuous table for data input. User will see form where he got incoming delivery No.  some information from other tables and as mentioned 41 items to measure 5 times ( 41 columns and 5 rows )

Hope that my explanation is clear and rly need your help i am screwed :D

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question is too broad to be answered. You should work yourself on the design of your database, and if you need help with *specific* issues, ask your questions. I can recommend you to look around in the web or in a library or bookstore for a good book or tutorial on databases, database normalization, and MS-Access. Design your database on paper first.

Comment: Also, it is not a good idea to post the same question twice. If your question is being downvoted, it's because it can be improved. Edit your original question. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: For what it is worth, "Running MS-Access" by Jon Viescas is a good book (I learned with it). It is a bit old (I bought it back in 1999), but has a very good chapter on database normalization.

Comment: I just deleted old post. so sry for double posting and for mr. Barranka i dont want to buy any more books my question is simple how can i create 1 record in incoming material table and or that exact record create X records in measurement table based on specific value in form.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "do-my-coding-work-for-me" place. You have to work yourself on your project, and if you have **specific** questions related to programming, then ask your questions.

Comment: Barranka yes i knew that this is not place like you mentioned but right now i am in time press and need to figure out some easy way whitch will do what i need that is why am i asking. If i had time to study DOA and ADO like i will eventually tomorrow i will not ask. But i got 3 days to created this. And just fyr i knew how to set up my db how to normalize it. Only thing which i dont know is how to force access create multiple records with same foreing id by 1 button. Records will be added later with continuose form.

Comment: Check my updated answer below. It contains an example on how you can write a procedure to do what you need. You'll need to fit the code to your specific needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. Use VBA to automate the creation of records. Look for information about `DAO` and/or `ADO`  and how to use them to insert records (I personally use `DAO` when I work with Access, it works but it's old).
2. **Do your homework**. Before asking a question, it is important that you do your research and that you try to solve the problems by yourself. Try to help yourself before asking others. **Please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)**.

---

Maybe this snippet of code can help you. You'll need to call this method from an event (`button_clic` or something in your form):

```
public sub addRecords(id as integer)
    dim db as dao.database, rsIn as dao.recordset, rsOut as dao.recordset
    dim strSQL as String
    dim someValue as integer, i as integer ' Test values
    ' "Connect" to your current database
    set db = currentdb
    ' Create a recordset with the input data you need (read only)
    strSQL = "select * from tbl_inputTable where id=" & id
    set rsIn = db.openrecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
    ' Create a recordset to your output table
    set rsOut = db.openRecorset("tbl_outputTable", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
    ' Read the data from the input table
    with rsIn
        .moveFirst
        someValue = rsIn![aField]
    end with
    ' Write some test data to your output table
    with rsOut
        for i = 1 to someValue
            .addNew
                rsOut![fk_id] = id
                rsOut![theValue] = i
            .update
        next i
    end with
    ' Close every recordset and databases (this does not close your application)
    rsIn.close
    rsOut.close
    db.close
end sub
```

In your input form, write this in the "On Click" event:

```
sub button1_click()
    call addRecords(txtId.value) ' I am assuming that there's a text box called "txtId"
end sub
```

This is just a sample of what you can do with `DAO`. I won't (and maybe nobody else would) write the full code for you: You'll need to fit this to your particular problem.